# How to display ;amp& in HTML?

Tags: html, escaping

I have to display this exact string in HTML:

```
;amp&
```

When I try it always changes to "&".

How to fix that?

Comment: The symptom is indeed correct for `&amp;`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you mean `&amp;`, then you need to double escape it:

```
&amp;amp;
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you actually meant `&amp;`, you just need to escape the `&`: use the HTML code `&amp;amp;`.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you mean `&amp;`

Why don't you do the following: `&amp;amp;` ?

Answer (score 2):

`;amp&` = `;amp&amp;`

Answer (score 1):

I guess you meant

```
&amp;
```

Because that DOES change into "&". Anyway - you will have to escape the ampersand.

So - replace "&" with "&" like:

```
&amp;amp;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is also the html entity for ampersand - `&#38;`, so if you want to print `&amp;`, just use `&#38;amp;`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display this exact string

```
;amp&
```

Then you you should do this...

```
;amp&amp;
```